# Is It haram to sell 'islamic art'

Tags: art

I wrote the name of Allah (SWT) on a small canvas, without representing living beings, is it haram to sell such an object? It's just a black Canvas with Allah written on It in Gold

Comment: I don't know, but I think to make profit by selling the name of Allah for money is a great evil. Surely getting money for your art work on it is a different thing. I am very curious about answers based on the Quran.

Comment: @GyroGearloose It's okay to make profit by selling objects that preserve the name of Allah SWT, even making profit of selling Quran is halah according to Ibn Qudamah, Ibn Abbas and the majority of Ulama.

Comment: @SalihMuhammed This what I think, but can you give a link or citation?

Comment: Here's Ibn Qudamah citation from Encyclopedia of Islamic Jurisprudence. I couldn't find a translation. https://t.ly/KLqE7

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not haram. Your work is similar to islamic calligraphy and you can make profit out ot it.